# Seamlessly Switch Between Tenants In Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, multi-tenant

So as of right now I have an app that has multiple tenants and I want to make it possible for a user that belongs to one tenant to log into another tenant that they belong to.

I am using AngularFire and I am logging a user in using the signInWithEmailAndPassword method like so:

```
signIn(email: string, password: string, companyId: string) : Promise<any> {
  firebase.auth().tenantId = companyId;

  return this.afa.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```

I specfically seen that inside of the firebase docs you cannot switch the tenant ID by resetting the:

```
  firebase.auth().tenantId = companyId;
```

So now I can only see one option that I dont like which is that every time a user switches their tenant they have to enter their password in again. Is there any way to avoid them having to do this?